# How do I modify an IIS FTP Authorization Rule for a specific path in C#?

Tags: c#, iis, ftp, servermanager

In Server 2008+ I am programatically creating new folders in a virtual directory, Reports, in the FTP site.  I can create a new FTP Authorization Rule for each new file path with:

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
ConfigurationSection authorizationSection = config.GetSection("system.ftpServer/security/authorization", "FTP/LDNClient/Reports/aClientPath");
ConfigurationElementCollection authorizationCollection = authorizationSection.GetCollection();

ConfigurationElement addElement = authorizationCollection.CreateElement("add");
addElement["accessType"] = @"Allow";
addElement["users"] = @"LDNClient";
addElement["roles"] = @"";
addElement["permissions"] = @"Read, Write";
authorizationCollection.Add(addElement);

serverManager.CommitChanges();
}
```

Where "FTP/LDNClient/Reports/aClientPath" is the path for the rule.  But there are a large number of elements for the same user with different paths.  If I open applicationHost.config I can see the different ConfigurationElements with the paths like, "aClientPath":

```
<location path="FTP/LDNClient/Reports/aClientPath">
    <system.ftpServer>
        <security>
            <authorization>
                <remove users="LDNClient" roles="" permissions="Write" />
                <add accessType="Allow" users="LDNClient" permissions="Read, Write" />
            </authorization>
        </security>
    </system.ftpServer>
</location>
```

But I can't figure out how to reference that one element so I can either (1) remove it or (2) modify the permissions.  I can roll through each node with:

```
foreach (ConfigurationElement item in authorizationCollection)  
{
   // Do something with item here
}
```

But I can find the path for aClientPath in "item". Using the location node above, how would I delete it or modify its permissions?

Comment: What do you exactly want to do by saying "how to reference that one element"? Do you want to iterate all location tags? If so, direct XML editing should be a much quicker way to go.

Comment: I want to find the location node/element with a specific path, like "FTP/LDNClient/Reports/aClientPath"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't totally understand why it had to be this way but I took a look inside the applicationHost.config file and duplicated it.  There was a remove of the "write" and an add of a "read, write".  Works so I'm going to call it good enough.

```
                ConfigurationElement addElement = authorizationCollection.CreateElement("remove");
                addElement["users"] = @"LDNClient";
                addElement["roles"] = @"";
                addElement["permissions"] = @"Write";
                authorizationCollection.Add(addElement);

                addElement = authorizationCollection.CreateElement("add");
                addElement["accessType"] = @"Allow";
                addElement["users"] = @"LDNClient";
                addElement["roles"] = @"";
                addElement["permissions"] = @"Read, Write";
                authorizationCollection.Add(addElement);

                serverManager.CommitChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample code that configuration manager provided for modifying permission. It will search element based on multiple attribute.

Not sure if it achieve your requirement.

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Web.Administration;

internal static class Sample {

    private static void Main() {

        using(ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager()) { 
            Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();

            ConfigurationSection authorizationSection = config.GetSection("system.ftpServer/security/authorization", "ftp/LDNClient/Reports/aClientPath");

            ConfigurationElementCollection authorizationCollection = authorizationSection.GetCollection();

            ConfigurationElement addElement = FindElement(authorizationCollection, "add", "users", @"LDNClient", "roles", @"", "permissions", @"3");
            if (addElement == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Element not found!");

            addElement["permissions"] = @"Read";

            serverManager.CommitChanges();
        }
    }

    private static ConfigurationElement FindElement(ConfigurationElementCollection collection, string elementTagName, params string[] keyValues) {
        foreach (ConfigurationElement element in collection) {
            if (String.Equals(element.ElementTagName, elementTagName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                bool matches = true;

                for (int i = 0; i < keyValues.Length; i += 2) {
                    object o = element.GetAttributeValue(keyValues[i]);
                    string value = null;
                    if (o != null) {
                        value = o.ToString();
                    }

                    if (!String.Equals(value, keyValues[i + 1], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
                        matches = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (matches) {
                    return element;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I can find the accessType, users, roles, and permissions.  What I can't find is the location attribute "path" like:

<location path="FTP/LDNClient/Reports/aClientPath">

Comment: @Velocedge When you load config.GetSection("system.ftpServer/security/authorization", "ftp/LDNClient/Reports/aClientPath"); It is always reading <location path> because authorization section is read-only in web.config and it is only writable in applicationhost.config